# how to apply patch uboot: Yocto project

Tags: patch, yocto

i'm trying to apply a patch during the creation of my image with bitbake commande.
i have my file: u-boot-tftp.pacth under the directory: /file/u-boot-tftp.
here is my u-boot-tftp.bbappend :

```
DEPENDS += "dtc-native"

SRC_URI = "file://u-boot-tftp.patch"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
```

while building my image, im having this error :

```
Applying patch u-boot-tftp.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?

No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
Patch u-boot-tftp.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
```

i tried to run the unpack commande : bitbake -c unpack -f u-boot-tftp but it din't work, i looked it up the internet and nothing seems to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

thanx

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `SRC_URI` variable in your bbappend. So the original U-Boot sources are not used and the U-Boot recipe has only your patch as the whole source.

Use `SRC_URI +=` instead of `SRC_URI =` in you bbappend (like you did with `DEPENDS`).

Comment: i rectified that, after that the     bitbake -c patch -f passes with success but when i try :    bitbake -c rootfs -f it gives me the same error. thanx

Comment: Please try `bitbake -c cleansstate u-boot-tftp` (or what is your u-boot's recipe name) and then `bitbake u-boot-tftp` to do cleanup and new build. BTW I don't have `rootfs` task for U-Boot (don't know what do you mean with `bitbake -c rootfs -f`).

Comment: I did clean my recipe with     bitbake -c cleansstate -f u-boot-tftp     then i tried rebuilding it with     bitbake u-boot-tftp    and i still get the same error. about the     bitbake -c rootfs -f     i told you i'm building a complete image and that commande is to force making the rootfs of your image, once that's done you can say making the zimage and the dtb is already going to pass. Now as for me the     bitbake -c patch -f     works but when i try to build the rootfs in order to complete building my image, that when this error reappears. thanx.

Comment: It is a blind shot, but I would remove the tmpdir to ensure that the whole build is clean (reusing of sstate should be fine). BTW I have `rootfs` task for image, but obviously not for U-Boot, so that's why I was puzzled. And I wouldn't use `-f` (it is usually not neede). I hope that you will find the solution otherwise.

Comment: i  removed the tmpdir and i tried           bitbake -c cleansstate -f u-boot-tftp then bitbake u-boot-tftp          , i'm still getting the same error. thanx for your interest in my question.

Comment: One more thing - I would double check that your patch can be cleanly applied to the U-Boot sources your are building (outside of OE).

Comment: if by double checking you mean applying the patch manually and then rebuilding my image with the patched file then yes i have done it before and the image was created. i'm currently trying to customize all the modifications i have done via Yocto recipes. thanx for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> can't find file to patch at input line 3

From the above error, it seems that yocto is unable to locate the patch. You can either update FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend path or change the directory where the patch is located.

While executing do_patch(), it will search patch for multiple paths which can be seen in build/tmp/work//u-boot-tftp//temp/log.do_patch. Check whether it searches for the patch in "/file/u-boot-tftp" folder or not. and update the path accordingly.

Comment: hi, i can say yocto has eventually located the patch but it couldn't locate the file to patch. i did copy the patch under file/u-boot-tftp and i retried  bitbake u-boot-tftp and there it is the same error: ERROR: u-boot-tftp-v2018.03-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/med/src_ibisv2/build0/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
Patch u-boot-tftp.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)

Comment: Maybe the patch isn't created at the right path level?